# TypeError: file1(...).copyColumns.copyTo is not a function. I am getting this error on apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a script that copies data from one sheet and pastes to another. The sheets can be in different workbooks and the data range can be multiple columns. Although I have made all the script that worked perfectly fine earlier, but I made some changes in it. Now it is showing `TypeError: file1(...).copyColumns.copyTo is not a function` this error. I know there might be just a small mistake that I am missing. I have spent 3-5 hours finding it but no luck. any help would be highly appreciated.

Script for File 1

```
function file1(url, sheet, selected_columns, headerRow) {
  url = "Workbook 1 url"
  sheet = "sheet to copy from"
  selected_columns = ['Column 1 Name', 'Column 2 Name', 'Column 3 Name']
  headerRow = '1'

  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
  copyColumns = []
  sheetsNames = []
  var sheets = file.getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) sheetsNames.push(sheets[i].getName())
  var selected_sheet = file.getSheetByName(sheet);
  var lastCol = selected_sheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn();
  var columns = selected_sheet.getRange(headerRow,1,headerRow,lastCol).getValues();
  for (i=0; i<selected_columns.length; i++){
    let column = columns[0].indexOf(selected_columns[i]);
    if (column != -1) {
      var copy = copyColumns.push(selected_sheet.getRange(1, column + 1, selected_sheet.getMaxRows()));
      Logger.log(column +1)
    }
  }

  Logger.log(sheetsNames)
  Logger.log(selected_columns)
  Logger.log(copyColumns)
  return {url, sheet, copyColumns}
}
```

Script for File 2

```
function file2(url, sheet, selected_columns, headerRow) {


  url = "workbook 2 url"
  sheet = "sheet to paste in"
  selected_columns = ['Column 1 Name', 'Column 2 Name', 'Column 3 Name']
  headerRow = '1'

  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
  pasteColumns = []
  sheetsNames = []
  var sheets = file.getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) sheetsNames.push(sheets[i].getName())
  var selected_sheet = file.getSheetByName(sheet);
  var lastCol = selected_sheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn();
  var columns = selected_sheet.getRange(headerRow,1,headerRow,lastCol).getValues();
  for (i=0; i<selected_columns.length; i++){
    let column = columns[0].indexOf(selected_columns[i]);
    if (column != -1) {
      var copy = pasteColumns.push(selected_sheet.getRange(1, column + 1, selected_sheet.getMaxRows()));
      Logger.log(column +1)
    }
  }

  Logger.log(sheetsNames)
  Logger.log(columns)
  Logger.log(selected_columns)
  Logger.log(pasteColumns)
  return {url, sheet, pasteColumns}
}
```

The script that runs both above functions together

```
function agg_test(){
  Logger.log(file1().copyColumns)
  for (i=0; i<file1().copyColumns.length; i++){
    file1().copyColumns[i].copyTo(file2().pasteColumns[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue and solution:

- I think that your showing error message of `TypeError: file1(...).copyColumns.copyTo is not a function` might be due to `file1().copyColumns.copyTo(` instead of `file1().copyColumns[i].copyTo(`. So I'm worried that your showing script might be different from the script for replicating your showing error message.
- If your currently showing script is used, I think that from `url = "Workbook 1 url"` of `file1()` and `url = "workbook 2 url"` of `file2()`, another error occurs like `Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet.`. I'm worried about this as the 2nd issue.
- And, in your following script,

  ```
    function agg_test(){
      Logger.log(file1().copyColumns)
      for (i=0; i<file1().copyColumns.length; i++){
        file1().copyColumns[i].copyTo(file2().pasteColumns[i]);
      }
    }
  ```

  - `file1()` and `file2()` is run several time. Please be careful this.

If your currently showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function file({ url, sheet, selected_columns, headerRow }) {
  var file = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
  copyColumns = []
  sheetsNames = []
  var sheets = file.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) sheetsNames.push(sheets[i].getName())
  var selected_sheet = file.getSheetByName(sheet);
  var lastCol = selected_sheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn();
  var columns = selected_sheet.getRange(headerRow, 1, headerRow, lastCol).getValues();
  for (i = 0; i < selected_columns.length; i++) {
    let column = columns[0].indexOf(selected_columns[i]);
    if (column != -1) {
      var copy = copyColumns.push(selected_sheet.getRange(1, column + 1, selected_sheet.getMaxRows()));
      Logger.log(column + 1)
    }
  }
  Logger.log(sheetsNames)
  Logger.log(selected_columns)
  Logger.log(copyColumns)
  return { url, sheet, copyColumns }
}

function agg_test() {
  var source = {
    url: "Workbook 1 url",
    sheet: "sheet to copy from",
    selected_columns: ['Column 1 Name', 'Column 2 Name', 'Column 3 Name'],
    headerRow: '1'
  };
  var destination = {
    url: "workbook 2 url",
    sheet: "sheet to paste in",
    selected_columns: ['Column 1 Name', 'Column 2 Name', 'Column 3 Name'],
    headerRow: '1'
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destination.url);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(source.url).getSheetByName(source.sheet).copyTo(ss);
  source.sheet = sheet.getSheetName();
  source.url = destination.url;

  var a = file(source).copyColumns;
  var b = file(destination).copyColumns;
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].copyTo(b[i]);
  }
  ss.deleteSheet(sheet);
}
```

- In this modification, the source sheet is copied to the destination sheet. And, the range is copied using your script. By this, the method of `copyTo(destination)` of Class Range can be used.

#### Note:

- At the above-modified script, it supposes that the source sheet has no formulas which are using other sheets. If your actual source sheet is such the sheet, please modify `agg_test()` as follows.

  ```
    function agg_test() {
      var source = {
        url: "Workbook 1 url",
        sheet: "sheet to copy from",
        selected_columns: ['Column 1 Name', 'Column 2 Name', 'Column 3 Name'],
        headerRow: '1'
      };
      var destination = {
        url: "workbook 2 url",
        sheet: "sheet to paste in",
        selected_columns: ['Column 1 Name', 'Column 2 Name', 'Column 3 Name'],
        headerRow: '1'
      }

      var src = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(source.url);
      var temp = src.getSheetByName(source.sheet).copyTo(src);
      var range = temp.getDataRange();
      range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
      var dst = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destination.url);
      var sheet = temp.copyTo(dst);
      source.sheet = sheet.getSheetName();
      source.url = destination.url;

      var a = file(source).copyColumns;
      var b = file(destination).copyColumns;
      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i].copyTo(b[i]);
      }
      src.deleteSheet(temp);
      dst.deleteSheet(sheet);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [copyTo(destination) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)
- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)